# Eclipse 3.4 package explorer question

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4, package-explorer

is it possible to do something like this: Let's say I have a lot of projects in my package explorer. I want to make different views. For example a view for projects I don't use very often, my main things, common things. Basically i want to clean up my package explorer to get a better overview of all my things. At the moment everything is in my head and all projects are overcrowding the package explorer. Is there any similar or recommended way to do this. Or let's just say how do you organize your things in the package explorer.

thx.

kuku

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use different **workspaces**. So you can use one workspace for project 1, 2 and 5 and the second for 3,4 and 6.

You can create a new workplace via **File --> Switch workspace --> Other**. Then you can choose a new folder and copy settings from the current workspace.

Otherwise, you can use **Working Sets**. Just play with them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with working sets.

In the pacakge explorer, there is a dowanward pointing triangle in the upper right corner. Click on it, and in the menu select "Top Level Elements -> Working Sets".

Then, you only have to define different working sets and can move projects into them using drag and drop.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using different **workspaces** or **working sets** there is also **Mylyn**, which can hide things not relevant to the current task.